# GeoDjango - Find all locations within X miles of provided point using bounding box

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to implement some search functionality for a web app, and have run into an issue where I don't know the proper functions to execute this.

Given a Point, a `bounding_box` database field with the EWKB representation of the geometry and a given distance value (aka 10km), I want to find all records that are within the radius or intersect with the outer boundary.

An example bounding box is:

```
0103000020E61000000100000005000000800F04E8AE1751C09EEE3F0181234640F04A8F5A600E51C09EEE3F0181234640F04A8F5A600E51C079B75A336B314640800F04E8AE1751C079B75A336B314640800F04E8AE1751C09EEE3F0181234640
```

Given that this function will be executed many times, with possible caching, I'd like to avoid any ST_BUFFER usage.

There are multiple things happening here:

1. How can I create a bounding box representation using the EWKB value in the `bounding_box` field?  Aggregate functions like ST_POLOGONIZE are not allowed within WHERE blocks.
2. Is ST_DWITHIN usage appropriate here?
3. This function will be executed many times.  What sort of optimizations are suggested?

Answer (score 2):

It is suggested to use the bounding box operators from PostGIS:

[PostGIS BBOX operators](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Operators)

The bounding box will be automatically derived from the geometries when you use one of the boundingbox operators, so no need to create a new bounding box geometry.

The `ST_DWITHIN` function as well as the bounding box operators usually exhibit a decent performance.